# Where do the words Builder and Container come from for an IoC Framework?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I use Autofac quite frequently and get confused using the variable naming convention "container" and "builder".

Sometimes it seems a "container" is "built".

Other times it seems a "container" "builds" dependencies it can resolve.

Sometimes I see developers call a "container" a "builder" and a "builder" a "container".

A great example is my own code today, using Autofac and NServiceBus and I have the following method in C#:

```
public BusConfiguration CreateConfigurationWithCustomContainer(Autofac.IContainer container)
```

And in the implementation, of that method:

```
BusConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(
                 customizations =>
                 {
                     customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(container);
                 }
            );
```

In this example, `NServiceBus.BusConfiguration` has a generic method called `UseContainer` and I am using the `Type` `NServiceBus.AutofacBuilder` and my argument, named `container` which is of `Type` `AutoFac.IContainer`;

**My Questions:**

1. So NServiceBus used the word "Builder" and AutoFac used the word "Container" are they the same thing conceptually to NServiceBus team
   and the Autofac team?
2. Where do the words "container" and "builder" come from in regards to an IoC framework?
3. How is a "container" and a "builder" different? Or are they the same in most circumstances, in regards to IoC Frameworks?

Answer (score 3):

### Builder

The [Builder Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) is a design pattern that commonly occurs in software. It is not specific to Dependency Injection. In fact, many DI containers do not even use the builder pattern.

That said, the modern view of how to use a DI container is to configure components in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), and then resolve one or more *object graphs* to set the application into motion. The builder pattern is well-suited to keeping this pattern from being violated (that is, it makes it difficult to register components at runtime).

### Container

A container is an IoC-specific concept, that generally refers to a software library or, more specifically, a part of a library that keeps track of abstraction-concrete type mappings and allows the user to resolve them. Autofac is one of many available IoC containers in .NET.